# Can I use a linear regression to analyse my data?

Tags: r, regression, residuals

I am conducting a research question where I need to analyse some data. To do this I was thinking of doing a linear regression, so I tired to model the residuals to check for linearity. I do not know how to interpret the results. Is it linear?

It is meant to be distributed evenly, be random and have no curvature.

[image]

Comment: From your image, it looks like you've used R to generate your model and plot the residuals, but you'd need to give us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you with actual analysis. More generally, here is a nice [post](https://www.codingprof.com/5-ways-to-check-the-normality-of-residuals-in-r-examples/) about how to use R to check the normality of your residuals - at a glance, your plot looks okay, but there are other plots to try, as well as formal statistical tests.

Comment: this random internet statistician's opinion: looks fine at a high level, your biggest issue is outliers. It would be great if you had a substantive explanation for the low points near 12.6, 12.8 and 13.1 on the x-axis: any thought as to why a model might overpredict these points? but I think you're OK to move on to p values/confidence intervals/whatever you were going to use this model for.

Comment: I'm not sure what "distributed evenly" is intended to mean. All of the likely meanings I can think of at present would be wrong.